# Bootstrap modal window does not close the second time that I open it

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open a remote modal window using Bootstrap. The page that opens the modal has the following code.

```
<a class="test" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Test</a>

<div class="modal-container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.test').click(function () {
            $('.modal-container').load(url, function (result) {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
     });
</script>
```

The remote page has the following code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            ... remote 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem that I have is that the first time the modal is called remotely it opens and closes normally but if I want to open it again, it does not close. If the modal (same code) is defined locally it works fine.

Please help

Comment: A fiddle might help us

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must close the first div and change role attribute on

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
```

try it!

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ... remote
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```